# Who first proved that every triangle has a circumscribed circle?

Tags: geometry, math-history

Wikipedia only mentions that it follows from the Cartesian equation for a circle:
$\left(x - a \right)^2 + \left( y - b \right)^2=r^2$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#cite_note-1

but I'm interested to know how far back this dates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Greeks knew this?

Comment: Almost certainly well before Euclid.

Comment: The argument given in your note, btw, is very hand-wavy and can easily be utilized to give some false results. The ancient Greeks would have had a geometric proof, not an algebraic one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Proposition $5$ in Book IV of Euclid's *Elements*.

Undoubtedly the result predates Euclid by many years, indeed centuries. But little pre-Euclidean material has survived.